# 2005 Ford Escape engine block exuding gas fumes

Tags: ford, escape, fuel-leak

Noticed a couple months back that fumes were entering the cabin through the ventilation. This occurred immediately after I had performed some work replacing the powertrain control module, all the ignition coils and all the spark plugs (removing upper intake manifold, etc).

Thought maybe I had not done a good enough job of reattaching fuel lines. Took advantage of some warmer weather today to take a look under the hood. Ran the engine while looking for any signs of leakage. Perhaps I wasn't able to see all the fuel lines, but I didn't see any actual leakage... Now I'm wondering if its possible for gas fumes to be expelling in some other way...

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated. At this point I'm thinking it might be best to just take it into the shop :(

Comment: You sure you properly reattached any airducts and funnels?(don't know how to call 'em) When i bought my car, it lacked one unther the bonnet, so it sucked air from under the bonnet instead of fresh air from outside. Even with all fuel lines connected, that smells like gasoline.

Comment: Does it smell like raw gasoline fumes? Or is it exhaust? Can you tell?

Comment: @CharlieRB it does smell like raw gasoline fumes, most definitely

Comment: @Bart so you're saying that it should exude gas fumes under the hood regardless? I did reconnect the air hoses but I'll have to take a second look just in case..

Comment: Well, it's not uncommon for an engine to disperse some smells. But if there's a strong scent of petrol, i'd suspect there's something wrong. If you're sure that you reattached all the fuel lines, i'd inspect all their connections to the engine. It's also possible for fuel hoses to 'sweat'. Especially if they're a bit old, dry, and have cracked. By detaching the fuel lines you may have bent them a bit, giving them the last little bit needed for them to create and open a crack.